# what means "もう駄目だと 一人孤独を抱いても" exactly

Tags: meaning

"もう駄目だと 一人孤独を抱いても"

i took this sentence from a song of uverworld (colors of the heart),
and i'd like to know what it means exactly.

i thought maybe it means something like:

"even if it is useless, i embrace the Loneliness".

this  "一人" between the sentence, confuses me;
 i don't know what it means in this sentence.
maybe it changes the meaning of the sentence, for example:

"its imposible to be alone, even if i embrace the loneliness".

also confuses me this "だと" in the sentence;
i down know what is his function.

thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translationfor this should be something like;

"even if I give up saying 'it's over' and embrace the loneliness on my own, "

## もう駄目だと

"「もう駄目だ」と"might be easier to understand.

"もう駄目だ" is often used when somebody gave up with the situation. A word-for-word translation would be something like "It is already(もう) bad(駄目)"
As you might know, "と" designates a quote.

## 一人孤独を抱いても

"一人で孤独を抱いても" might be easier to understand.

"一人で" is used to emphasis the word "孤独". It is rather obvious that if you are "孤独", you are "一人". However, by explicitly saying so, it shows how strong the loneliness is.

Comment: thank you. i think that i understand this sentence a bit better. the 一人 in the sentence was what confused me. one question more: this (だと) in the sentence also means something like (even, or if ) or it just designates a quote?. it could also be that the (だ )and the (と) are separated and (だ) is part of (駄目だ) and (と) designates a quote. it confuses me because in the in the original sentence, in the lirycs of the song (もう駄目だ) wasn't in  parentheses (this thing 「」)

Comment: I didn't notice your comment. Sorry about that. As for your question, this cannot be separeted to "もう駄目" and "だと" because it has no following "なら".

Comment: Maybe my explaination above is wrong. It is clear that it cannot be separated so, but I'm not quite sure with the reason